# updating problem in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: updates

I am using `sudo apt-get update` command for updating. While updating Ubuntu it shows :

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 is obsolete. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Releases

Answer (score 1):

Run the below commands in terminal to remove the lock.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Then you can run,

`sudo apt-get update` command.

Comment: while updating ...